# Setting a dashboard as home in Grafana

Tags: grafana

Is there a way to set a dashboard in Grafana as the home without admin login ? I have a Helm chart that I deploy Grafana with so I would like to do this at a configuration level.

I could not see any options under http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/ for `grafana.ini`

I'm able to do this manually by login as the admin for the default organization, starring a dashboard and setting that dashboard as the home under preferences. But ofcourse automating this through configuration would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to do it via .ini file. But you could make use of the Grafana API to get this done.

If you can figure out the Id of the dashboard.[Or create via the API itself](http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/dashboard/#create-update-dashboard)

Use [/api/user/stars/dashboard/{id}](http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/user/#star-a-dashboard) to star the dashboard

Then [update preference](http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/preferences/#update-current-user-prefs) to set the dashboard as home.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup might be able to do it with the API in a post deployment task. This was my other option. Just thought there would be an easier option